# Add a different class to each item

Tags: php, css

I have a problem with long article titles at my homepage. https://i.stack.imgur.com/WAPNV.jpg

I've tried to condense it to one-line by putting the HTML/CSS code in plugins like sourcerer or rokcandy, however it causes a problem - HTML code is sent too for head's >title< and >meta< tags.

I have a "jm-lifestyle" template which shows 9 articles at homepage. Sadly, every element has the same class, so I'm trying to add different classes for all of them.

I found the path of php file which shows the title

> components\com_content\views\featured\tmpl\default_item.php

```
<?php if ($params->get('show_title')) : ?>
<h2 class="item-title" itemprop="name">
```

So I'm trying to add a different class of h2 by this way:

```
<?php
foreach (range('a', 'i') as $letter);
?>
<h2 class="item-title_<?php echo $letter  ?>" itemprop="name">
```

However it makes item-title_i everywhere. I'm not really familiar with php, could you help me how to get another letter in all nine paragraphs? It's important to being not random. I would like them to stay alphabetically (or just the same everytime), so I could make different CSS classes for them. Unless, maybe you have easier way to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

Your output needs to be within the foreach loop:

```
<?php
foreach (range('a', 'i') as $letter) {
?>
<h2 class="item-title_<?php echo $letter  ?>" itemprop="name">
<?php
}
?>
```

If you do update default_item.php then make sure you override it in your template. Never override core files or changes are likely to be lost when you patch the site.

I think the simplest solution would actually to use the nth-child selector in CSS.  I don't think you actually need to update the HTML to achieve what you are trying to do.

That said, your question seems to suggest a fundamental design mistake, and trying to solve it with code could come back to bite you.  A CMS should be dynamic and handle various sizes of content - if you are writing new code each time you add an article, then it is not working as a CMS.  Any aesthetic design decision that harms usability isn't a good design choice.  Having titles not line up really isn't going to bother any user as long as all the text is skim-readable and clear.  If the lack of vertical alignment really bothers, have them in a single column rather than two columns.

Trying to get too much vertical alignment in the days of responsive design seems a waste of time.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You are right, it's not a good way to solve it, but I would like to end it.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that "enter" will send the post :)

Comment: I've tried both methods (PHP and CSS). 
CSS's nth-child doesn't work well, I don't know why. I made something like this (with next children), but the first is shown at all h2.item-title.
`h2.item-title:nth-child(1){
 background:red;
 letter-spacing:-1px; 
 word-spacing:-1px;
 margin-left:10px;
 font-size:23px !important;
 
 }`
I've tested too for 'even' or 'odd' function of nth-child, but it works for all h2's or for nothing and I don't know why.

Comment: PHP method makes nine h2 classes for all nine paragraphs, but the right one which is shown is still with 'i' letter. 
`
<h2 class="item-title_a" itemprop="name">
</h2><h2 class="item-title_b" itemprop="name">
[TOO LONG POST SO I'VE DELETED IT]
</h2><h2 class="item-title_h" itemprop="name">
</h2><h2 class="item-title_i" itemprop="name">
<a href="/dotkom_czerwiec2016/index.php?option=com_content&amp;view=article&amp;id=39:dd&amp;catid=21&amp;Itemid=211" itemprop="url">
   Short title, no problem  </a>
</h2>`